# XMLStarlet, XPath - How to remove attributes depending on node

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xmlstarlet

I'm trying to use XMLStarlet to transform this (test.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns:doc="http://www.test.com" doc:id="hello">
  <a doc:id="x"/>
  <a doc:id="x"/>
  <c doc:id="x">
    <a doc:id="x"/>
    <a doc:id="x"/>
    <c doc:id="x"/>
  </c>
</root>
```

into this (removing the `doc:id` attribute on all nodes except `c`):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns:doc="http://www.test.com" doc:id="hello">
  <a/>
  <b/>
  <c doc:id="hello">
    <a/>
    <b/>
    <c doc:id="hello"/>
  </c>
</root>
```

I've tried this, but it removes all of the `doc:id` attributes:

```
xml ed -N doc="http://www.test.com" -d "//@doc:id[not(self::c)]" test.xml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this concatenation of two xmlstarlet commands:

1. The first one deletes(`-d`) all `doc:id` attributes which are not part of a `<c>` element (as you already did)
2. The second part of the command updates(`-u`) the values(`-v`) of all `doc:id` attributes of the `<c>` elements.

This is the command:

```
xml ed -N doc="http://www.test.com" -d "//*[not(self::c)]/@doc:id" -u "//c/@doc:id" -v "hello" test.xml
```

The output is as desired.